# Failed to send SMS in Hindi

Tags: php, api, sms

I need to send SMS in hindi, for this I need to pass the hindi string through URL.

As I am coading in php I used `urlencode($hindimessage)` on string and passed complete URL through `file_get_contents()`. On executing I got error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://IP GOES HERE/smpp/sendsms?username=$name&password=******&to=$contact&from=DEMOTT&coding=3&&text=%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%B7+%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%81%E0%A4): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported
```

Without using urlencode(), the server treats text as EMPTY STRING and rejects.

I also tried Using utf8_encode() encoding. I recive message in HTML tags like `&#2361;&#2368;`....

But when I use the API URL directly I am able to recive the message in hindi since API is Unicode API coding=3 enbled for Hindi text.(i.e API is working Properly)

Please Inform what kind of approach I need to adopt for sending message in both Hindi as well as in English.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: file_get_contents() needs a proper url with a file name which u are missing. Check the actual API url and I suppose parameter would be your hindi text.

Comment: I use the complete url but problem remain same, The same URL I pasted in the URL tab, the SMS is recieved. But it creates error during execution. English text deliver successfully in same manner.

Answer (score 1):

`urlencode()` is necessary if you are calling URL in `file_get_contents()` function.

You need to adopt **CURL** for sending message in both Hindi as well as in English.

```
 $smsgatewayurl = 'http://IP GOES HERE/smpp/sendsms';
 $post_data = array(); // All params including text message

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $smsgatewayurl);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
 $output = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
```

CURL is best option to call third party APIs compare to file_get_contents function. I have tested this above function with spring edge sms gateway including hindi text.

Answer (score 0):

Set dcs coding =8 and convert your Hindi characters into Unicode characters and put it in the text field.This will work.